# Is "Has your headache gone?" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I saw on one site that you usually don't say "My headache has gone," and "My headache is gone" is commonly used instead.

However, there is this "Has your headache gone?" question in my textbook.
Is this question grammatically correct?

Comment: A native speaker is also likely to say "My headache's gone" where the _'s_ could be interpreted as either 'is' or 'has'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I guess the question on my textbook is grammatically ok.

Comment: Which site? Note that verbs of motion **used to be** commonly conjugated with *be,* much as French still is; but this less and less common, and usually now restricted to certain special cases. "Has gone" is **far** more common.

Comment: @And I intuit that *gone* has become more adjectivyTM in AmE than in BrE. *headache is gone, headache is bad, headache is back, is your headache gone? Is your mother gone? (out, away). I'm afraid he's (is) gone. (dead)* all seem common and natural to US American me. *Gone* has it's own entry in the first three major online dictionaries I looked at. Labelled *adj.* for this use. (Granted dictionaries are no good as authorities on word classes. But again, I'm thinking adjective-like enough to work with as copular complement.)

Comment: When I imagine hearing *Has your headache gone?* I picture either someone putting on a pompous act, or a Brit (and must tell myself to watch my stereotypes). But I think if someone said it "normally"/quickly/IRL, I probably wouldn't notice whether *have* or *be* was used.

Comment: Does headache have legs? I prefer the more common way "Is your headache gone?"